# Missing Edit form in SharePoint

Tags: edit-form, missing

I have a serious problem with the Edit Form on one of my lists. It has disappeared. I opened it to look at and know that you cannot make changes to it, doesn't allow changes. So I abandoned the idea and built pages to do that same work I want. The edit form on the list is gone now. I'm confused.  Anyone got any ideas how to get the standard page back? I tried building a power app form but it doesn't work no matter what I try.  I remember these issues in 2003 and 2007. Pretty much the same stuff. However, back then we had designer that actually could build new forms.  Now we can't and that has taken away functionality that we all use.  Is there anyone out there that can help with this issue?

Comment: Are you using SP online modern experience? Can you try using default forms from List settings > Form settings?

Comment: You can also get default list form URLs using PowerShell: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/03/sharepoint-online-get-default-list-form-new-edit-display-urls-using-powershell.html